# Cannot find Database Mail option in My SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-mail

I could not find the Database Mail option in my SQL server 2014 under SQL server `instance -> Management`. Where can I enable it?

Comment: Check this one first https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187540(v=sql.105).aspx then check here to enable it https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161956(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What version of SSMS ,what edition of SQL, and do you have permissions?  I ask that  in case you are simply not seeing it due to privileges

Answer (score -1):

If it is Express Edition you cannot do it using GUI but you can do it using a query:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@account_name = 'MailTest',
@description = 'Sent Mail using MSDB',
@email_address = '<emailaddress>',
@display_name = '<anyname>',
@username='********',
@password='******',
@mailserver_name = 'mail.*******.com'

-----------------------------------------------adding profile
 EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
@profile_name = '*****',
@description = 'Profile used to send mail'
-------------------------------------------------adding profile to account
 EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = '*******',
@account_name = 'MailTest',
@sequence_number = 1
---------------------------------------------
 EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@profile_name = '********',
@principal_name = 'public',
@is_default = 1 ;

--------------------------------------------reference
 SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_configuration
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_principalprofile
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount


---------------------------------------------triggering the mail
 exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = '******', @recipients = '*********@********.com',
 @subject = 'Mail Test', @body = 'Mail Sent Successfully',
 @body_format = 'text'


---------------------------------------------
 sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = '*******', @recipients = '*********@*********.com',
 @subject = 'Mail Test', @body = 'Mail Sent Successfully for the second time',
 @body_format = 'text'
 ,@query = N'SELECT * from test.dbo.session_add',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

References:

- [Sending Mail using SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/) (SQL Server Central blogs)
- [Enabling Database Mail on SQL Server Express](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/01/60245.aspx) by Mladen Prajdić